# Как отсортировать массив, который был строкой?

Tags: php

Есть строка с текстом, довольно большая.
Вопрос: как на выходе отсортировать и вывести, что такое слово встречается столько раз, а такое слово - столько раз. И чтобы это было отсортировано по убыванию.
Например в таком формате: слово - кол-во раз.

Я смотрел в сторону мультисорт, но мне кажется, это не то.

Comment: @oldzas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

1. `strtolower();` - приводим строку к нижнему регистру
2. `preg_replace();` - удаляем все знаки препинания
3. `explode();` - разделяем строку по пробелу в массив
4. `array_count_values();` получаем количество повторения в массиве
5. `Profit!`

Вроде не сложный алгоритм, реализуйте сами =)